# Unable to create database using sqflite_common_ffi plugin for flutter desktop

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I want to create database for flutter desktop application. I am using sqflite_common_ffi plugin for this purpose but the issue is it doesn't me to create database and giving some error on onCreate method call.

```html
 // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    var databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    print('DATABASE PATH: $path');
    Database db = await databaseFactory.openDatabase(
      path,
      options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
             $columnType TEXT NOT NULL,
               $columnStatus TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnFlag INTEGER NOT NULL
          )
          ''');
          print('TABLE CREATED');
        },
      ),
    );
    print('DATABASE CREATED');

    return db;
  }
```

This my code for creating database. When i run the application it gives the following error:

[image]

Anyone please help me out. Thanks

Comment: hey @Dev94 can you please share code for sqlite for desktop. i really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked these steps:

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi#windows

> Should work as is in debug mode (sqlite3.dll is bundled).
>
> In release mode, add sqlite3.dll in same folder as your executable.
>
> sqfliteFfiInit is provided as an implementation reference for loading
> the sqlite library. Please look at sqlite3 if you want to override the
> behavior.

Comment: Yes, I was missing that one line command sqfliteFfiInit(); in main method. Thanks, it is fixed now